# How use Sigma.js to view .gexf file in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, data-visualization, graph-visualization, sigma.js

I know nothing about javascript and little of html, I have a .gexf file made in Gephi that I want to be able to view and manipulate in browser (or at least outside of Gephi)
I've been using the following website as a resource http://sigmajs.org/ but its 'tutorial' code brings up nothing for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Network Graph</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #sigma-container {
            max-width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            margin: auto;
        }
     </style>

</head>

<body>
    <h1> Testing </h1>
    <div id="sigma-container"></div>
    <script src="sigma.js-master/sigma.js"></script>
    <script src="sigma.js-master/plugins/sigma.parsers.gexf/sigma.parsers.gexf.js"></script>
    <script>
        sigma.parsers.gexf(
            'Data_Dictionary_Network_Graph.gexf',
            {
                container: 'sigma-container'
            },
            function(s) {

            }
        );
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something glaringly obvious, but I don't know js at all and only basic html, sigma.js just happened to be the only plugin I could find for what I wanted